# Getting console error in Double Linked List using Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working in Doubly linked list and I am getting console error

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined
at window.onload (VM263:46)"
```

Here is a link to the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/krunalcp/pnhjnuc1/7/)

```
var node = {
  value: val,
  next: null,
  previous: null
}

function DoubleLinkedList(){
    this.head = null;
}

DoubleLinkedList.prototype.push = function(val){
    var head = this.head,
    current = head,
      previous = head;

  if(!head) {
    this.head = { value: val, previous: null, next: null };
  } else {
    while(current && current.next) {
    previous = current;
    current = current.next;
   }
   current.next = {value: val, previous:current, next:null}
  }
}
```

I got the reference from the below [source](http://thatjsdude.com/interview/linkedList.html)

Can someone please help me by solving the error and get it work?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `val` in `node`?

Comment: I hope it's the variable. I am learning and got the reference from the about mentioned source.

Comment: You "hope it's the variable"? What variable? That's exactly why the error is there -- it's not defined.

Comment: Hey, I am learning it. I have no idea, why the error is coming. If you think you can solve it, please use the jsfiddleto edit the code to solve.

Comment: In the guide you linked, I'm pretty sure the author just left it as `val` for you to change. Give `val` a literal value or define the variable.

Comment: in this part: `var node = {
  value: val,
  next: null,
  previous: null
}` you reference a variable `val` that is not defined in your code. And that's that the error is saying. Either you define the variable or stop using this not defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, val is not defined anywhere in your code, yet you use it

Answer (score 0):

the node = {...} part is used in the source you provided as a way to show you how the data will look in a node, but is not part of the code. You need to delete that part.

Also, if you can't figure out which bits to copy-paste, I think you might be a bit ahead of yourself. Try going back to how variables and objects work and try to really understand them.